# Show more/less content in sidebar depending on height

Tags: css

I have a blog with main content and a sidebar.  Most posts have photo galleries with 30+ photos.  In the sidebar I display the thumbnails and a "more" link.  By default I show 6 thumbnails.  I would like to show up to all 30 if there was a enough content to make the sidebar long enough to support them.

I have found and come up with my own javascript solutions but I would really like to know if there is a CSS only method (even it requires not-fully-supported CSS techniques).

Maybe some kind of nth-child kind of thing?

**Edit:** I don't want to the sidebar to be longer than the content.  That's why I'd only show more if the room was available.

Comment: You want us to code? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, with Javascript.  I keep adding thumbnails to the sidebar and then comparing the height of the sidebar to that of the content until the sidebar height surpasses.  With CSS I haven't found anything... and I think that the answer is it can't be done.  I thought I'd ask here as a last ditch effort in case I'm missing something simple.